# Xcode crash (stop) when he reaches a breakpoint (mix project)

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode6, breakpoints

This question looks like it has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135009/xcode-6-1-and-6-1-1-crashes-on-debugger-breakpoint-simulator), but since it is not answered and it is maybe not the same problem, I ask myself.
I use everything on last version (Xcode 6.1.1, Pods and a swift project inside my app as a core).

If I add a breakpoint or if app crash on the main of my app, I always get a crash of Xcode. If the breakpoint or the crash is inside the swift core project, it won't crash, but use po myVar will crash Xcode.

For the moment I can live with the second crash, but the first one is really too hard for me as I have to make quickly a screenshot each time Xcode will crash to figure what's going on and try to debug (and wait to reload everything).

I hope someone will understand this Xcode crash log and help me.

```
Process:               Xcode [701]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.1.1 (6611)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6611000000000000~4
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       810788292
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [701]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2014-12-08 10:53:34.748 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        8AB8EC6D-DC04-2B25-FD83-704CE00176D4


Time Awake Since Boot: 4000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        19  <DBGLLDBSessionThread (pid=2045)>

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000090

VM Regions Near 0x90:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010bc31000-000000010bc32000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A2008a

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b752e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b669f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afddb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afdcfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afdc838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8f04443f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8f0441ba ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8f043ffb _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff995a36d1 _DPSNextEvent + 964
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff995a2e80 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010c36c6fd -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 237
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff99596e23 -[NSApplication run] + 594
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff995822d4 NSApplicationMain + 1832
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff94ea55c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bd22e kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9bd1ba6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b752e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b669f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afddb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afdcfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afdc838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff9500dd20 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ed19b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc3f6 __select + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b752e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b669f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afddb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afdcfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afdc838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ed1bab9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000011a36b1d2 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 676
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ed19b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b752e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b669f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afddb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afdcfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afdc838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff997067a7 _NSEventThread + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b752e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b669f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afddb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afdcfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afdc838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ed1bab9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ee1745f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x000000011bf6e9eb -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ed19b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001160daebe -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 519
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ed19b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001160daebe -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 519
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ed19b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001160daebe -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 519
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ed19b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b752e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b669f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afddb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afdcfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9afdc838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9b092ed1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff8d54fb8f SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 463
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:: Dispatch queue: parsing queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916b756a semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9bd1fc55 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 213
2   com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices  0x000000010dbe5fda -[DTXMessageParser waitForMoreData:incrementalBuffer:] + 87
3   com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices  0x000000010dbe5c08 -[DTXMessageParser parseMessage] + 50
4   com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices  0x000000010dbe59c6 __43-[DTXMessageParser initWithMessageHandler:]_block_invoke + 35
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9bd1d323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9bd18c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9bd1c365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9bd1decc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9bd1b6b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9bd29fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f816cb _pthread_wqthread + 729
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 16:: lldb.debugger.io-handler
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc306 __read_nocancel + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9c237f6b __srefill1 + 24
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9c2317fb fgets + 104
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011408928d lldb_private::IOHandlerEditline::GetLine(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, bool&) + 341
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000114089718 lldb_private::IOHandlerEditline::Run() + 176
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113fabee0 lldb_private::Debugger::ExecuteIOHanders() + 86
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113fb2f4a lldb_private::Debugger::IOHandlerThread(void*) + 14
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 17:: <lldb.process.gdb-remote.async>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000114055325 lldb_private::Condition::Wait(lldb_private::Mutex&, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 109
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001140b8332 lldb_private::Predicate<bool>::WaitForValueEqualTo(bool, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 90
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113fbd2ee lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEventsInternal(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, lldb_private::Broadcaster*, lldb_private::ConstString const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 324
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113fbd405 lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEvent(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 27
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001140c2d9a ProcessGDBRemote::AsyncThread(void*) + 1228
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 18:: <lldb.process.internal-state(pid=2045)>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000114055325 lldb_private::Condition::Wait(lldb_private::Mutex&, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 109
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001140b8332 lldb_private::Predicate<bool>::WaitForValueEqualTo(bool, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 90
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113fbd2ee lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEventsInternal(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, lldb_private::Broadcaster*, lldb_private::ConstString const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 324
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113fbd405 lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEvent(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 27
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011416b7bc lldb_private::Process::WaitForEventsPrivate(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&, bool) + 114
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000114171ffe lldb_private::Process::RunPrivateStateThread() + 226
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000114171b21 lldb_private::Process::PrivateStateThread(void*) + 9
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 19 Crashed:: <DBGLLDBSessionThread (pid=2045)>
0   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113fbc046 lldb_private::FileSpecList::GetSize() const + 4
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011413cc58 lldb_private::CompileUnit::GetSupportFiles() + 36
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001140ebb4b SymbolFileDWARF::GetLoadedModules(lldb::LanguageType, lldb_private::FileSpecList&) + 127
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113fe8b2a lldb_private::Module::GetSwiftASTContext() + 1464
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001140e10b8 SymbolFileDWARF::GetSwiftASTContext() + 66
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001140ec5d9 SymbolFileDWARF::ParseType(lldb_private::SymbolContext const&, DWARFCompileUnit*, DWARFDebugInfoEntry const*, bool*) + 137
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001140e7dd4 SymbolFileDWARF::GetTypeForDIE(DWARFCompileUnit*, DWARFDebugInfoEntry const*) + 188
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001140e7c61 SymbolFileDWARF::ResolveType(DWARFCompileUnit*, DWARFDebugInfoEntry const*, bool) + 99
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001140dfcfa SymbolFileDWARF::ResolveTypeUID(DWARFCompileUnit*, DWARFDebugInfoEntry const*, bool) + 330
9   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001140e5d00 SymbolFileDWARF::ResolveTypeUID(unsigned long long) + 96
10  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000114154736 lldb_private::SymbolFileType::GetType() + 36
11  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011401bb0d lldb_private::ValueObjectVariable::GetClangTypeImpl() + 21
12  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011400df4d lldb_private::ValueObject::MaybeCalculateCompleteType() + 37
13  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000114011ddb lldb_private::ValueObject::GetObjectRuntimeLanguage() + 31
14  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011416d474 lldb_private::Process::IsPossibleDynamicValue(lldb_private::ValueObject&) + 68
15  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000114013204 lldb_private::ValueObject::CalculateDynamicValue(lldb::DynamicValueType) + 90
16  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001140132ab lldb_private::ValueObject::GetDynamicValue(lldb::DynamicValueType) + 65
17  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011284984a ValueImpl::GetSP(lldb_private::ProcessRunLock::ProcessRunLocker&, lldb_private::Mutex::Locker&, lldb_private::Error&) + 276
18  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112843caa lldb::SBValue::GetSP(ValueLocker&) const + 58
19  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112843da1 lldb::SBValue::GetName() + 41
20  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x00000001127a992a -[DBGLLDBDataValue initWithLLDBValueObject:forStackFrame:withParent:updateSummary:] + 247
21  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x00000001127a97cc -[DBGLLDBDataValue initWithLLDBValueObject:forStackFrame:withParent:] + 92
22  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x00000001127a6e75 ConvertValueListToDBGDataValueArray(lldb::SBValueList const&, unsigned int, DBGLLDBStackFrame*, NSArray*) + 305
23  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x00000001127a6d05 -[DBGLLDBStackFrame _getAllFrameVariablesOnLLDBSessionThread] + 144
24  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x00000001127a8445 -[DBGLLDBStackFrame _getLocalsFromLLDBOnSessionThread] + 48
25  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x00000001127bc0ad -[DBGLLDBSession handleNextActionWithState:withRunPending:] + 424
26  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x00000001127b6e89 DBGLLDBSessionThread(void*) + 1052
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f812fc _pthread_body + 131
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f81279 _pthread_start + 176
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff916bc946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93f7f4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 19 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000154728218  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000154728164  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000088  rsi: 0x0000000000000001  rbp: 0x0000000154728120  rsp: 0x0000000154728120
   r8: 0x0000000154728160   r9: 0x000000015472a000  r10: 0x0000000000000050  r11: 0x00007fcd20500000
  r12: 0x00007fcd20927c58  r13: 0x0000000000000002  r14: 0x0000000000000088  r15: 0x0000000000000053
  rip: 0x0000000113fbc046  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x0000000000000090

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x020000b8
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
{I can post it if needed but have to remove some part to don't exceed characters limit}

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 9
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 3008
    thread_create: 2
    thread_set_state: 94

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=403.2M resident=152.2M(38%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=251.0M(62%)
Writable regions: Total=1.7G written=430.1M(25%) resident=504.1M(29%) swapped_out=94.5M(6%) unallocated=1.2G(71%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
Activity Tracing                     2048K
CG backing stores                    7952K
CG image                             41.4M
CG raster data                        604K
CG shared images                      368K
CoreAnimation                        1804K
CoreData Object IDs                  4100K
CoreImage                               8K
CoreUI image data                     348K
Dispatch continuations               8192K
Foundation                           3584K
Image IO                             1392K
JS JIT generated code                   8K
JS JIT generated code (reserved)      1.0G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                       8K
MALLOC                              540.8M
MALLOC (admin)                         32K
Memory Tag 242                         12K
Memory Tag 249                        156K
Memory Tag 251                          8K
OpenCL                                 40K
SQLite page cache                    22.2M
STACK GUARD                          56.1M
Stack                                19.3M
VM_ALLOCATE                          19.5M
WebKit Malloc                         464K
__DATA                               44.4M
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                          103.9M
__TEXT                              299.3M
__UNICODE                             544K
mapped file                         609.7M
shared memory                           4K
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                 2.7G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space        1.7G


Model: Macmini5,1, BootROM MM51.0077.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.76f0
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xE4), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.1f2 15015, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500,11 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Comment: enable exception brealpoint , then it will move to actual problem in the code

Comment: Is the crash occurring when you are in Swift code and you are using Obj-C objects? And do you happen to have the case where your Obj-C is external? For example, not in the same path structure as the majority of your code (like an external project?).

Comment: @Hameed I do have Exception Breakpoint, but as it crash when exception or stopping in a breakpoint, it can't help me

Comment: @MobileBen The crash occur on my main project, whatever it is ObjectiveC or Swift. I do have external swift code (if I understand correctly I hope) but it is all in Swift. Inside this code, nor breakpoint nor exception won't crash xCode. It is maybe the reason of misleading in xCode, I can try to explain you better the situation if you still think that will help.

Comment: The problem I ran into was only in the swift code. I reported it to Apple already as I believe it is a very real problem. The issue is that even though the code compiles and the header search paths are correct, the swift code will crash on breakpoint if you don't have the full path of the header file in the bridging file. So for example, instead of `#import "MyObjCClass.h"`, you'd need something like `#import "/Users/jdoe/project/ExternalLibrary/MyObjCClass.h"`. However based on what you say, it doesn't sound like this is the case.

Comment: You give me some hope, but I just try and a break point on my main project (a swift file) still crash xCode. I always send report to Apple but still 2 or 3 versions of xCode later and still not fixed :(